# How to see history of TortoiseSVN svn commands which have been run?

Tags: windows, svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN is very useful for simplifying the process of using subversion.

However if you switch to linux and just want to use the command line it would be useful to see the commands that you have run with TortoiseSVN to see how you would run the equivalent steps at the command line.

So is there a log or a setting in TortoiseSVN that allows you to see the svn commands that have been run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not display the svn command line that you have run with TortoiseSVN for the simple and good reason that TortoiseSVN does not run any svn command.
However you have description of equivalence between TortoiseSVN actions and svn command lines here: "[Command Line Interface Cross Reference](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli.html)". The important note is the following:

> Even though there are CLI equivalents to what TortoiseSVN does, remember that TortoiseSVN does not call the CLI but uses the Subversion library directly.

For info, you have possibility to see the TortoiseProc command (not the svn command) just before you run them. In the settings window, select Advanced, find the setting called Debug and set it to true. Not useful if you switch to Linux.